# How to extract base64 text value from HTML tags

Tags: javascript

I have HTML code that looks something like this:

```
<p>gfgrgfgf</p><ul><li>fgfgfgf</li></ul><p><br></p><p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS...">
```

Each `img src=` value is an image in a base64 format.
This block of HTML contains multiple such `img src=`s.

How can i extract all of their values (the base64 string) while of course ignoring other HTML tags?

Comment: You have HTML as string ? or raw HTML ?

Comment: It is contained in a JS string.

Comment: Are you looking for the value of `src` or just the base64 value?

Comment: The whole value in `src`, including the `data:image/jpeg;base64` part.

Comment: @Gambit2007 you can use a HTML parser API and than select the img elements using querSelector and get the src attribute

Comment: I think an important detail i left out is that i'm using React.. not native JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse your js string, and `map` the array of images to get their `src` :

```js
const str = `<p>gfgrgfgf</p><ul><li>fgfgfgf</li></ul><p><br></p><p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS...">`;

const html = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");

const result = [...html.images].map(e => e.src);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm getting `ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined`? (using React)

Comment: using react shouldn't be an issue, try `window.DOMParser()...`

Comment: Yeah, it seems like i can't use it in the `render` method or the `constructor`, but elsewhere it works.

Answer (score 1):

I created a pen here: https://codepen.io/dantehemerson/pen/pozLxZy

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      // Create the ref for the container
      this.containerRef = React.createRef();
    }

  handle = e => {
    // all images
    const allImgsCollection = this.containerRef.current.getElementsByTagName("img")

    // Transform to array to manipulate
    const allImgsArray = Array.from(allImgsCollection);


    // regex that match base64 images
    const reg = new RegExp('^(data:\\w+\\/[a-zA-Z\\+\\-\\.]+;base64,)(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\\/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=)?$', 'i')

    // All images in base64
    const allbase64Images = allImgsArray.map(item => item.getAttribute('src')).filter(item => item && reg.test(item))

    // See the console
    console.log('All base64 images: ', allbase64Images)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      // Link the container to textInput Ref.
      <div ref={this.containerRef}>
         <h1>Base 64 images</h1>
        <p>
          No base 64
        <img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/m/v/Y/E/V/small-red-apple-md.png' width={100}/>
        </p>
        base64
        <img src={img1} width={100}/>
        <div>
          <p>
            base 64
            <img src={img2} width={100}/>
          </p>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handle}>Get all img base64 (See console)</button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

const img1 = "data:image/png;base64,i..."
const img2 = "data:image/png;base64,i..."

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a queryselector to select all items, then filter the ones that don't have a src that starts with data. Then you can map that filtered list to get the src values.

```js
let str = `<p>gfgrgfgf</p>
<ul>
  <li>fgfgfgf</li>
</ul>
<p><br></p>
<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS..."></p>
<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS..."></p>
<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS..."></p>
<p><img src="//example.com/img.png"></p>`

// Create a placeholder element we can add html to
let frag = document.createElement('div')
// Add the string to the placeholder
frag.innerHTML = str

// Search the placeholder for img tags
let items = [...frag.querySelectorAll('img')]
   // Remove items that don't start with data
  .filter(img => img.getAttribute('src').startsWith('data'))
  // Get the value of the src tag
  .map(img => img.getAttribute('src'))
  
console.log(items)
```

Comment: Thank you but that didn't work with React, i'm sorry i forgot to mention it.